# Edit option from Radio Buttons in PHP

Tags: php

I am VERY new to PHP and editing some code

Currently it has two radio buttons.  Selecting either will bring up some options.

I am wanting to get rid of one option (pick up) and have the page just show the delivery option.

Any help would be ace, I have tried playing with the code but no luck!
[image]

```
<div class="top10 row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 ">
              <?php echo CHtml::radioButton('trans_type',false,array(
               'class'=>"trans_type",
               'value'=>'pickup',
               'required'=>true
              ));              
              ?>
              <span><?php echo Driver::t("Pickup")?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 ">
              <?php echo CHtml::radioButton('trans_type',false,array(
               'class'=>"trans_type",
               'value'=>"delivery"
              ));              
              ?>
              <span><?php echo Driver::t("Delivery")?></span>
            </div> <!--col-->
          </div> <!--row-->

          <div class="delivery-info top20">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?php echo CHtml::textField('contact_number','',array(
                  'class'=>"mobile_inputs",
                  'placeholder'=>Driver::t("Contact nunber"),
                  'maxlength'=>15
                ))?>
              </div> <!--col-->
              <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                <?php 
                echo CHtml::textField('email_address','',array(
                  'placeholder'=>Driver::t("Email address")
                ))
                ?>
              </div> <!--col-->
            </div> <!--row-->

            <div class="row top10">
              <div class="col-sm-6 ">
              <?php echo CHtml::textField('customer_name','',array(
                'placeholder'=>Driver::t("Name"),
                'required'=>true
              ))?>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6 "><?php echo CHtml::textField('delivery_date','',array(
                'placeholder'=>Driver::t("Delivery before"),
                'required'=>true,
                'class'=>"datetimepicker"
              ))?></div>
            </div> <!--row-->

            <div class="row top10">
             <div class="col-sm-12 ">
             <?php 
             $map_provider = Driver::getMapProvider();
             ?>

             <?php if ($map_provider =="mapbox"):?>
                <div id="mapbox_delivery_address" class="mapbox_geocoder_wrap"></div>
             <?php elseif ( $map_provider=="google.maps"):?>
                <?php 
                 echo CHtml::textField('delivery_address','',array(
                   'class'=>'delivery_address geocomplete delivery_address_task',
                   'placeholder'=>Driver::t("Delivery Address"),
                   'required'=>true
                 ));
                ?>
             <?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the lines of code below (or comment them out while you try it). Make a copy of the file before you make any changes in case you need to back out the attempt.

```
 <div class="col-xs-6 ">
              <?php echo CHtml::radioButton('trans_type',false,array(
               'class'=>"trans_type",
               'value'=>'pickup',
               'required'=>true
              ));              
              ?>
              <span><?php echo Driver::t("Pickup")?></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that! Oh I tell you something, I learnt the hard way about not saving the code somewhere before! Only make that mistake once!